# dd/MM/yyyy date format in jsp by scriptlet

Tags: java, javascript

I want to show the date coming from data base in the jsp page in dd/MM/yyyy format. Here is my code in javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <%
         SDateDTO sDTO = (SDateDTO) request.getAttribute("sDTO");  
    if(null != scholAvailDTO){
        System.out.println(scholAvailDTO.getEndDate());
    %>

        var end = <%=scholAvailDTO.getEndDate() %>;
        $("#endDateId").val(end);
       <%       
    }
    %>

});
```

In console it is coming 27/04/2010 but in jsp it is getting populated like 0.0033582089552238806 which is actually division result of the date. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks, Amit

Answer (score 2):

If `getEndDate()` returns `java.util.Date` object then, use `DateFormat` for get the formatted string and then wrap the value in quotes as below:

```
    <%DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");%>
    var end = "<%=formatter.format(scholAvailDTO.getEndDate()) %>";
```

If `getEndDate()` returns `java.lang.String` then simply wrap the value in quotes as below:

```
   var end = "<%=scholAvailDTO.getEndDate() %>";
```

Comment: See my answer - I don't believe the problem is the string format, it's that it's not being treated *as a string*. (In particular, the fact that `System.out.println` is showing the right format suggests that it would be rendered in the same format into the Javascript.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: In that case also, I believe this should help as the output will be string type. NO?

Comment: No, because the contents of the result will just be the string data, not a *string literal* with double quotes at the start and end. That's my point: think about what the browser sees. The OP presumably wants `var end = "27/04/2010";` - what do you expect to add those double quotes?

Comment: You're assuming that `getEndDate()` returns a `Date` to start with, and I suspect it doesn't - I suspect it already returns a string, given the question. (A `Date` wouldn't be converted to a string using that format by default.) Additionally, you're using minutes rather than months in the format, and you've got months and days the wrong way round...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Updated again. Hope its fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes - your Javascript will presumably be rendered to the browser as:

```
var end = 27/04/2010;
```

If you want it to be *in a string literal* then you'll need to add the quotes yourself:

```
var end = "<%=scholAvailDTO.getEndDate() %>";
```

Note that you'll need to be confident that the value itself doesn't have quotes - or other values which aren't appropriate for JavaScript - in there. I suspect there may well be a better approach than the above.